# Why doesn't the each() function work with inputs attached to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the `.each()` function to capture values from the inputs, however it only works with the inputs present in the DOM.

I am using jQuery to insert more HTML entries. These added inputs are not bound in the DOM, so `.on()` is used to attach these fields to the DOM.

My goal is to add up all the values of each input added by the user.

Here is an excerpt from the code:

```
$("form").on("click", "#calc", function () {
    var total = 0;
    $('#1 .val').each(function(){    /* HERE IS THE PROBLEM */
       var valor = Number($(this).val());
       if (!isNaN(valor)) total += valor;
    });
    alert(total);
});
```

[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/hiporiqoro/edit?html,output) for my website

Comment: Please add the needed html to reproduce your problem.

Comment: there's a missing closing quote for the id property of the input: `<input type="number" name="valor[]" placeholder="e aqui..." required="" id="btn-desc-'+btn_id_desc+'-'+(qtd_input)+'**"** class="val">` [See JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/hazozaxiqu/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to a missing `"` character delimiting the `id` you give to the `input` elements you append, as such the `class` is lost.

To fix this you can use template literals, which remove the need for spaghetti string concatenation, and also you can remove the `id` attribute on the dynamic content as it's an anti-pattern. This will leave you with simpler code that's more extensible and far easier to maintain.

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").on("click", ".add-campo", function() {
    let $container = $(this).closest('.descricao_rot');
    let qtd_input = $container.find('.val').length;
  
    if (qtd_input < 10) {
      $container.append(`<br><label for="valor">Valor</label> <input type="number" name="valor[]" placeholder="e aqui..." required="" class="val">`);
    } else {
      alert("Ainda não é possivel adicionar mais descrições");
    }
  });

  $("form").on("click", "#calc", function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.val').each((i, el) => total += Number(el.value) || 0);
    alert(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="add-pub" method="POST">
  <div id="formulario">
    <br/>
    <hr>
    <div class="corpo-form" id="corpo1">
      <h4>Dia 1</h4>
      <br/><br/>
      <div class="descricao_rot">
        <label for="valor">Valor</label>
        <input type="number" name="valor[]" placeholder="e aqui..." required="" class="val">
        <button type="button" class="add-campo"> + </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
  <div class="botoes">
    <button type="button" id="calc"> Calcular </button>
  </div>
</form>
```